# Transferring external images & files to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, md5

If I use the Google Cloud Storage File Transfer console

> https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfer?project=XXXX

How do I generate an MD5 string for my image? Say my image is located at `https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg` for example.

I can easily get the bytes value, but how would I generate the MD5 for this?

The docs were a bit vague. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An MD5 hash is used to ensure the data transferred into GCS is imported correctly. HTTPS data transfers include a variety of built-in checksums, but for very large imports of many, many files, errors can and do show up, and so GCS wants to be sure that each object that it downloads is exactly what you think it is.

An MD5 is a 128 bit number that is the result of running the MD5 algorithm on an object. This number can be represented in a variety of ways (the popular md5sum command uses hexadecimal strings). GCS asks that you represent this number as a base64 encoding. Here's a command that can generate an MD5 sum in the right format:

```
openssl md5 -binary NameOfSourceFile | openssl enc -base64
```

There's a standard GCS object that can be used to validate your MD5 logic. The object https://storage.googleapis.com/md5-test/md5-test has a base64'd MD5 string of `BfnRTwvHpofMOn2Pq7EVyQ==`.